# SQL Wildecard Query in PHP

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to create a restaurant search that will find the restaurant in the database even when the user only inputs part of the whole name.

Here is the code:

First I take the input, sanitize it and then add the `%` signs to the left and right.

```
$restaurantNameTest = InputCleaner($_GET["restaurantName"]);
$restaurantName = ('%' . $restaurantNameTest . '%');
```

Then I run the query:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, 
"SELECT restaurantID,restaurant_name, cusine, wait_time
FROM Restaurant
WHERE restaurant_name = '$restaurantName'");
```

For some reason this isn't working and no results are found unless I type in the name perfectly. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: why do you put `$restaurantName` in brackets? Those brackets are not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Like instead

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, 
"SELECT restaurantID,restaurant_name, cusine, wait_time
FROM Restaurant
WHERE restaurant_name LIKE '$restaurantName'");
```

Comment: That was it! Thank you!

Comment: use it and you will got sql injection with get parameter. right answer is with ``bind_param``

Comment: Hi Raven, as I'm sure this guy is probably doing a school study and you're right that bind_param and mysqli is better. My answer is not wrong.

The question is not: "how do I write proper code" Because then I'd tell him to stop using PHP, and writing queries directly at all.

Simply going to proper safe functions is still crappy programming.

Good day.

Comment: every code **should** be proper even it's php. this world already have too much vulnerabilities to generate one more.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of an SQL question than a PHP question, but what I believe you need is the [LIKE comparison](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) of the WHERE clause.

So change your query to read: `...WHERE restaurant_name LIKE '$restaurantName'");`

`LIKE` will match partial strings, based on the placement of the wildcard (`%`) character(s).

Answer (score 1):

So a few things to note, first of all to echo what others have said -- you should be using `LIKE` in your query. On top of that you should really be using MySQLi's [`prepared statements`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

So you will want a your code to look something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT restaurantID,
               restaurant_name, 
               cusine, 
               wait_time
        FROM   Restaurant
        WHERE  restaurant_name LIKE '%?%'";

$query = $connection->prepare($sql);
$query->bind_param('s'. $restaurantName);

$query->execute();
```

I'm primarily a `PDO` user so you may want to double check the above syntax, but it should work.

**To re-iterate on your question specifically:**

- Use `LIKE` with your `wildcards` to get the result you're after and not `=`.

Comment: Is not his question though, but true.